# Позиционирование относительно другого элемента

Tags: html, css

```css
body { 
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/Yk5r87S.png") center center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.container {
  font-size: 18px;
  left: 30%;
  top: 35%;
  position: fixed;
}
.button {       
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 73px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  <div class="button">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Как добиться того, чтобы текст будущих кнопок при изменении разрешения экрана точно попадал в рамки фоновой картинки (как при разрешении 1920x1080)? Фон должен оставаться резиновым.

Пытался, но 100% точности позиционирования под разные разрешения не получается сделать.

Comment: Есть подозрение, что с `background-size: cover` без джаваскрипта никак. Вам обязательно накладывать именно на такой фон? Отрисовать рамочки нужной резиновости через HTML+CSS не вариант?

Comment: @andreymal фон с рамками у меня вообще другой (видео), и ещё сложнее, что через CSS его не сделаю, а здесь я для примера взял простую картинку

Comment: Да уж, совсем грустная история. Видимо, нужно делать примерно как пишет Zhihar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты использовал стиль `background-size: cover;` который может привязываться или к максимальной ширине или к максимальной высоте родительского контейнера, поэтому, на мой непрофессиональный взгляд, воспользоваться css будет проблематично и надо  позиционировать программно (с помощью javascript).

В рамках jQuery:

С этой целью надо создать обработчик resize, внутри которого будешь

- определять новый размер окна
- вычислять новый размер изображения
- зная размеры нового и старого изображения и зная в какой точке должен находиться текст из простого соотношения вычисляешь новое положение точек

  x_new = x_old * width_new / width_old

Comment: Точка — координаты?

Comment: да, точка - это {x, y} того места ка изображении, где должен начинаться текст.

Например изображения 1000x500, позиция текста на нем {215, 100}. Изображение было растянуто до 1500x750, значит координаты должны быть {215 * 1500 / 1000, 100 * 750 / 500} = {322, 150}

Вот в эту координату и надо позиционировать текст

Answer (score 2):

Как такой код поддерживать будешь? 
Сделай отдельно фон и отдельно кнопки.
Фон у тебя по центру позиционирован, сделай чтобы кнопки тоже были по центру позиционированы всегда. Текст внутри кнопки.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/216273)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, вообще-то он прав.

Comment: @Qwertiy по существу? вполне возможно. но формат комментария, мне кажется, совсем не годится при написании ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да вроде вполне конкретно написал, как переверстать нормально.